# Magento config xml - inherit value

Tags: magento

Using the stores node in config xml - is it possible to manipulate the inherit values (i.e. the checkboxes that determine the scope of website or store value)

So for example the config path for phone under general is: General > Store Information > Phone

so in xml i would target this as:

```
<stores>
        <my_store_code>
            <general>
                <store_information>
                    <phone>111 222 333</phone>
                </store_information>
            </general>
        </my_store_code>
    </stores>
```

But how do i then make sure this value is used over website.  The path appears to be phone_inherit though i have been unable to target that directly via xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state of the checkbox is determined by whether or not a value is set in the core_config_data table.

You can see this in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config::initFields():
Line 295 (Magento 1.7.0.0):

```
if (isset($this->_configData[$path])) {
    $data = $this->_configData[$path];
    $inherit = false;
} else {
    $data = $this->_configRoot->descend($path);
    $inherit = true;
}
```

`_configData` is an array of paths/values loaded from the core_config_data table. If the path is set (in the database), it uses the value and sets $inherit to false (unchecked); otherwise, it looks for the value in the scope config (`_configRoot`) and sets $inherit to true (checked).

The scope config is based on what you have set in admin under "Current Configuration Scope". So if you have a store view selected, it'll look for the `general/store_information/phone` value under `stores/my_store_code`. Depending on your configuration, this could return a store value, website value, default value, or nothing; store values override website values, and website values override default values.

This means that, in the configuration, there is no way to explicitly say "inherit from website". Instead, Magento mimics this by adding/removing values from the database when you change the value of the "use website/default" checkbox. Magento adds a row in core_config_data when you uncheck the box and enter a custom value. Likewise, Magento will delete the row and look in the scope config if you elect to use the "website/default" value.

For example, you can have "use website" checked, but Magento will use the store value if you have it specified in your config.xml file. A bit confusing, but that's how it works. So, if you want your store to use the website value, you need to remove your store configuration xml for that value.